# snprintf vs std::stringstream

Tags: c++, printf, stringstream, secure-coding

I am working on removing `SECURITY CODING` violation in my product. My code has lot of `sprintf`, coverity tool is suggesting me to use `snprintf`, But C++ also has `std::stringstream`. Will it be a good idea to use `std::stringstream` in place of `snprintf`

Comment: it depends on what you find important, if it is performance, use snprintf, if it is type safety, use stringstream

Answer (score 6):

`std::stringstream` is typesafe, use operator <<, use internal buffer, part of C++, not so fast as `sprintf`.
`sprintf` is not typesafe, not use c++ operators, use external buffer, use elipsis, which can works only with POD types, inherited from C, fast.